# Getting direct link form redirect link

Tags: php

i want to get link from redirected by php click counter

```
http://www.mymaza.com/songs/pakistani_pop/download/pakistan.php?id=168
```

this page redirect to

```
http://sound5.mp3pk.com/pakistani/sajjad_ali/babia/babia1(www.songs.pk).mp3
```

i want to get redirected page link

However i tried other method seems it like not easy

Comment: add your patter of redirecting, or is it just from this particular url to url ?

Comment: yes i want url to url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to resolve a given URL:

```
function resolveURL($url) 
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $resolved = curl_getinfo($ch);
    return $resolved['url'];
}
```

Usage:

```
echo resolveURL('http://example.com/someurl.php?foo=42')
```

Comment: Using as function is good option i already save your previous code and convert into function nice to see this is now in fucntion

Comment: @user2236950: I recommend implementing some sort of error handling to make sure you always get the output you expected. Good luck!